# write a vim operator for deleting the whitespace before a line

Tags: vim

I want to write a vim command to delete the whitespace before a line. I try two different things:

```
"delete the whitespace before a line
nnoremap gll  <esc>^d0

"delete the whitespace for the lines in visual block
vnoremap gl   <esc>:'<,'>normal ^d0<cr>
```

These are two very simple commands, and now I want to make `gl` to be operator like `d` and `c`, and `gll`  delete the black for a line. I wish `gl` can do these things:

1. `2gll` command will delete the whitespace for 2 lines.
2. I don't need `gl` to support word motions like `w` and `e`, because my 'delete whitespace' command acts on lines.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

if I understood you right, you are looking for the command `:left`

Mapping `gll` for example,  to `:left<cr>`, should work.

for the visual mapping, `:left` works too.

Comment: Yeah, I think the OP wants the mapping to work like a normal-mode operator though.

Answer (score 0):

Simply writing:

```
nnoremap gll :normal ^d0<CR>
```

will make `2gll` do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty mapping:

```
nno gll :<C-U>exe ',+' . (v:count-1) . 'left'<CR>
```

Explanation:

```
<C-U>   remove the range automatically added to the command line
exe     execute a string as a normal command
',+' . (v:count-1) 
        build a string containing (1) a range of the current line
        to the v:count-1 line (v:count holds the count given to
        the mapping)
left    and (2) the command to left-align text
<CR>    execute the string
```

Rereading your question, perhaps you want to define
an operator mapping:

```
fun! Left(type)
    '[,'] left
endfun
nno gl :set opfunc=Left<CR>g@
```

See `:help :map-operator`.

`g@` is a normal-mode command that waits for a motion before calling the function specified by the `'opfunc'` setting. In the function, the `'[` and `']` marks refer to the start and end lines defined by the motion.

Now `gl` can be used before a motion command.
So `gll` will remove the indent of the current line, `glap` will remove
the indent of the current paragraph, etc. You'll need to do tiny bit of extra
work to support visual-mode, but it's clearly explained in the help file.

Finally, the way I achieve this is to simply do, e.g. `<ap` and then hit `.` a few times. :-)